# Journey Builder Email activity: "Not Sent" - is it possible to find out why?

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

We are using Journey Builder to send out transactional emails. I am reviewing one of these journeys and I can see that the email activity has a small number of "Not Sent", which I assume means they entered the journey and marketing cloud decided not to send to them for some reason.

[image]

The email activity uses a Transactional send classification (since it is a transactional email), which as I understand ignores subscription status, so I'm guessing it's not that.

Is there a way that I can find out why they were not sent? I couldn't find anything in the documentation about what this actually means.

[edit] just wanted to add that while it is possible to click on some of the numbers and percentages to drill down, the Not Sent number is not clickable.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be due to various reasons:

1) The email is not sent to those contacts because there might be some ampscript logic in your email that might be looking or fetching some value from a Data Extension or real time which is not present for those contacts. Hence, it is resulting into failing of that logic and thus preventing from sending the email.

2) If you have used RaiseError() function in your email, it will prevent the email from sending if it does not meet the specified condition.

3) If you have set up a goal in your journey and the journey has reached the specified goal, the contact will exit out of the journey and the steps will be skipped, hence preventing from sending emails.

As per the description that you have provided, I strongly feel that you are fetching some value for these contacts which is not present in the DE for those contacts.

In this case please check the history of your journey to see which contact has failed to receive the email. You can then Preview and View your email for that particular contact and see if you are able to successfully Preview it for him. If not then check the value in DE that you are fetching from it.

Let me know if you catch the issue.

Comment: Thanks Krati, I looked in the history and found a failed one with this message:
"Failed - A subscriber error occurred invoking triggered send. StatusMessage: Unable to queue Triggered Send request. There are no valid subscibers. ErrorCode: 180008 SubscriberFailureDescription: Error Code: 24 - Subscriber was excluded by List Detective"
I have created a case with SMC support to understand why I get this error.